# Intermediate layer makes tensorflow optimizer to stop working

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder

This graph trains a simple signal identity encoder, and in fact shows that the weights are being evolved by the optimizer:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
initia = tf.random_normal_initializer(0, 1e-3)

DEPTH_1 = 16
OUT_DEPTH = 1
I = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1], name='I') # input
W = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[1,DEPTH_1], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True) # weights
b = tf.get_variable('b', shape=[DEPTH_1], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True) # biases
O = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(I, W) + b, name='O') # activation / output

#W1 = tf.get_variable('W1', shape=[DEPTH_1,DEPTH_1], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32) # weights
#b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', shape=[DEPTH_1], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32) # biases
#O1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(O, W1) + b1, name='O1')

W2 = tf.get_variable('W2', shape=[DEPTH_1,OUT_DEPTH], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32) # weights
b2 = tf.get_variable('b2', shape=[OUT_DEPTH], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32) # biases
O2 = tf.matmul(O, W2) + b2

O2_0 = tf.gather_nd(O2, [[0,0]])

estimate0 = 2.0*O2_0

eval_inp = tf.gather_nd(I,[[0,0]])
k = 1e-5
L = 5.0
distance = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square( eval_inp - estimate0 ) )

opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-3)
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(distance, [W, b, #W1, b1,
  W2, b2])
clipped_grads_and_vars = [(tf.clip_by_value(g, -4.5, 4.5), v) for g, v in grads_and_vars]

train_op = opt.apply_gradients(clipped_grads_and_vars)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  for i in range(10000):
    print sess.run([train_op, I, W, distance], feed_dict={ I: 2.0*np.random.rand(1,1) - 1.0})
  for i in range(10):
    print sess.run([eval_inp, W, estimate0], feed_dict={ I: 2.0*np.random.rand(1,1) - 1.0})
```

However, when I uncomment the intermediate hidden layer and train the resulting network, I see that the weights are not evolving anymore:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
initia = tf.random_normal_initializer(0, 1e-3)

DEPTH_1 = 16
OUT_DEPTH = 1
I = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1], name='I') # input
W = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[1,DEPTH_1], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True) # weights
b = tf.get_variable('b', shape=[DEPTH_1], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True) # biases
O = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(I, W) + b, name='O') # activation / output

W1 = tf.get_variable('W1', shape=[DEPTH_1,DEPTH_1], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32) # weights
b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', shape=[DEPTH_1], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32) # biases
O1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(O, W1) + b1, name='O1')

W2 = tf.get_variable('W2', shape=[DEPTH_1,OUT_DEPTH], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32) # weights
b2 = tf.get_variable('b2', shape=[OUT_DEPTH], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32) # biases
O2 = tf.matmul(O1, W2) + b2

O2_0 = tf.gather_nd(O2, [[0,0]])

estimate0 = 2.0*O2_0

eval_inp = tf.gather_nd(I,[[0,0]])

distance = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square( eval_inp - estimate0 ) )

opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-3)
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(distance, [W, b, W1, b1,
  W2, b2])
clipped_grads_and_vars = [(tf.clip_by_value(g, -4.5, 4.5), v) for g, v in grads_and_vars]

train_op = opt.apply_gradients(clipped_grads_and_vars)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  for i in range(10000):
    print sess.run([train_op, I, W, distance], feed_dict={ I: 2.0*np.random.rand(1,1) - 1.0})
  for i in range(10):
    print sess.run([eval_inp, W, estimate0], feed_dict={ I: 2.0*np.random.rand(1,1) - 1.0})
```

The evaluation of `estimate0` converging quickly in some fixed value that becomes independient from the input signal. I have no idea why this is happening

**Question:**

> Any idea what might be wrong with the second example?

Comment: How are you verifying the weights are "evolving"?

Comment: @EvanWeissburg in the second example `W` values barely change, `distance` does not get smaller and in the inference loop `estimate0` barely changes value with different inputs. In first example `W` change, `distance` become of the order of 1e-5 in a hundred steps and `estimate0` closely tracks the input value

Comment: The answer below is very good. Another hint: try some other optimizer like Adam instead of plain Gradient Descent. You could even try another activation function like leaky relu for example.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**TL;DR:** the deeper the neural network becomes, the more you should pay attention to the gradient flow (see [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/301285/130598) of "vanishing gradients"). One particular case is **variables initialization**.

---

### Problem analysis

I've added tensorboard summaries for the variables and gradients into both of your scripts and got the following:

**2-layer network**

[image: 2-layer]

**3-layer network**

[image: 3-layer network]

The charts show the distributions of `W:0` variable (the first layer) and how they are changed from 0 epoch to 1000 (clickable). Indeed, we can see, the rate of change is much higher in a 2-layer network. But I'd like to pay attention to the gradient distribution, which is much closer to 0 in a 3-layer network (first variance is around `0.005`, the second one is around `0.000002`, i.e. 1000 times smaller). This is the **vanishing gradient problem**.

Here's the helper code if you're interested:

```
for g, v in grads_and_vars:
  tf.summary.histogram(v.name, v)
  tf.summary.histogram(v.name + '_grad', g)

merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('train_log_layer2', tf.get_default_graph())

...

_, summary = sess.run([train_op, merged], feed_dict={I: 2*np.random.rand(1, 1)-1})
if i % 10 == 0:
  writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=i)
```

### Solution

All deep networks suffer from this to some extent and
there is no universal solution that will auto-magically fix *any* network. But there are some techniques that can push it in the right direction. Initialization is one of them.

I replaced your normal initialization with:

```
W_init = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
b_init = tf.constant_initializer(0.1)
```

There are lots of tutorials on Xavier init, you can take a look at [this one](http://philipperemy.github.io/xavier-initialization/), for example.
Note that I set the bias init to be slightly positive to make sure that ReLu outputs are positive for the most of neurons, at least in the beginning.

This changed the picture immediately:

[image: 3-layer-improved]

The weights are still not moving quite as fast as before, but they are moving (note the scale of `W:0` values) and the gradients distribution became much less peaked at 0, thus much better.

Of course, it's not the end. To improve it further, you should implement the full autoencoder, because currently the loss is affected by the `[0,0]` element reconstruction, so most outputs aren't used in optimization. You can also play with different optimizers (Adam would be my choice) and the learning rates.

Comment: this is why i use keras and not tensorflow directly - sensible defaults

Comment: thank you for this response, it sent me on the right track

Comment: What do yo mean by that @denfromufa. What are sensible defaults in tensorflow?  You always have to set the initializer and stuff like that yourself and choose the right optimizer.

Comment: @Maxim I cannot really see the difference between your result after xavier initialization and before. The weights seem to be the same whereas the gradient changes a tiny bit. But where is the big difference?

Comment: @thigi pay attention to the variance of grad distribution. It jumped from `~0.000002` to `~0.1`. That is more than enough for NN to learn

Comment: okay, so the peak itself is okay. I get it! What about the kernel weights that seem to stay the same? they should change in order to make it "better" --> lower loss

Comment: If the grad hasn't collapsed to 0, how can they stay the same. It's ok if the changes are not dramatic, you can always boost up the learning rate a bit if you'd like. They are changing as long as the grads haven't vanished and that's fine.

Comment: Okay, and what is a practical lower bound for the gradients? I have some gradients with variance of 0.001. Is that already vanished?

Comment: `0.001` looks rather small to me, especially if you feel that the NN has a long way to learn. I think you should dig further and see why exactly they are so small. Activation? Dying relu? Add extra batch norm?

Answer (score 0):

That looks very exciting. Where exactly does this code belong? I've only recently discovered TensorBoard

is this in callbacks somehow:

```
  for g, v in grads_and_vars:
  tf.summary.histogram(v.name, v)
  tf.summary.histogram(v.name + '_grad', g)

merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('train_log_layer2', tf.get_default_graph())
```

is this after fiting:

```
_, summary = sess.run([train_op, merged], feed_dict={I: 2*np.random.rand(1, 1)-1})
if i % 10 == 0:
  writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=i)
```