# Tensorflow does not update linear weights during backpropagation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

#### Problem

In my recurrent model (sequential binary classifier) at each time step `t` I need to perform the following input transformation:

`[32 x 4] --> [32 x 100]`

So, if my sequence length is 3, I should have:

```
[32 x 4] --> [32 x 100]
[32 x 4] --> [32 x 100]
[32 x 4] --> [32 x 100]
```

I do it by applying linear transform `xW + b` on `[32 x 4]` tensor at each time step `t`.  My working Torch implementation of the model shows the **mean** of linear weigths change each epoch:

```
Epoch #1    
0.0012639100896195
0.0012639100896195  
0.0012639100896195

Epoch #2    
0.0039414558559656
0.0039414558559656
0.0039414558559656

Epoch #3
-0.0099147083237767 
-0.0099147083237767 
-0.0099147083237767
```

The backward pass updates the weights, everything works.
However, when I attempt to do the same in Tensorflow the **mean** stay the same or updated very slightly at each epoch:

```
Epoch: 1
> lr update: 0.0497500005
#################### DEBUGGING ####################
0.051794354      Model/input_layer2/linear_weigth:0
0.06118914   Model/input_layer2_bias/linear_bias:0

Epoch: 2
> lr update: 0.049500001
#################### DEBUGGING ####################
0.051794227      Model/input_layer2/linear_weigth:0
0.06118797   Model/input_layer2_bias/linear_bias:0

Epoch: 3
> lr update: 0.0492500015
#################### DEBUGGING ####################
0.051794235      Model/input_layer2/linear_weigth:0
0.06118701   Model/input_layer2_bias/linear_bias:0
```

Tensorflow linear implementation is very simple:

```
def linear(input)
    return tf.add(tf.matmul(input, self.linear_weight), self.linear_bias)

expanded = [linear(batch_seq) for batch_seq in unstacked_input]
```

Both `self.linear_weight` and `self.linear_bias` are trainable and are initialized as `tf.Variables` during graph construction. Both Torch and TF models use identical training datasets, hyperparameters. Torch and TF model size (number of params) are the same as well. Needless to say that Torch model trains and shows good results on test data while TF model does not train at all.

#### Question:

Since I am new to TF, could you give some tips what could be wrong with TF model? I understand that's a very long shot without complete code but maybe I am missing something TF specific here.

#### Info

You might have noticed that in Torch we have 3 mean values per each linear operation at time step `t` while in TF I get 2 means -- one comes from linear and the other from bias. If instead of `linear()` I use `tf.layers.dense` call without `name` parameter I actually have 3 mean values per dense call. But in that case TF will create a different mean value per dense call which we don't want to do.

Here is the training chunk of TF code which should do all the forward/backward magic but it does not:

```
if self.training:
    self.lr = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)
    tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
    # clip the gradient by norm
    grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(self.cost, tvars), config.grad_clip)
    # update variables (weights, biases, embeddings...)
    with tf.name_scope("optimizer"):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr)

        # compute grads/vars for tensorboard
        self.grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)

        # debugging only, this is how I get the weights and grads
        for g, v in self.grads_and_vars:
            self.param_vals[v.name] = v
            self.param_grads[v.name+'_grads'] = g

        self.train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars),
                        global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())
```

#### Tensorboard

Tensorboard screenshots after the model stopped training after 38 epochs due to validation loss do not descrease anymore. I am also not very familiar with TB and I can only tell that something is definitely not right according to histograms.

```
# collecting data for tb
tf.summary.scalar("Training loss", model_train.cost)
tf.summary.scalar("Learning rate", model_train.lr)
tf.summary.histogram("Training loss", model_train.cost)

for g, v in model_train.grads_and_vars:
    tf.summary.histogram(v.name, v)
    tf.summary.histogram(v.name + '_grad', g)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tensorboard charts clearly show vanishing gradient problem. You might want to look at a similar problem and solution [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48816873/712995)

Comment: You are correct, this however is not the only issue with the above implementation. Long story short I had to use `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE` and `trainable=False` for `tf.layers.dense` call to make it work like in original Torch model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I was applying `loss = tf.sigmoid(logits)` (as in original Torch model) and then feeding `loss` to `tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy`. This brought gradients to nearly zero and the weights were not updated properly. When I removed `tf.sigmoid` function the gradients increased the weights started moving.

```
logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(last_layer, self.output_w, self.output_b)
floss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy
#floss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
loss = floss(self.targets_input, logits, weights=1.0, label_smoothing=0,
             scope="sigmoid_cross_entropy", loss_collection=tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES)
```