# How to monitor gradient vanish and explosion in keras with tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, tensorflow-gradient

I would like to monitor the gradient changes in tensorboard with keras to decide whether gradient vanish or explosion. What should I do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To visualize the training in Tensorboard, add [`keras.callbacks.TensorBoard`](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard) callback to `model.fit` function. Don't forget to set `write_grads=True` to see the gradients there. Right after training start, you can run...

```
tensorboard --logdir=/full_path_to_your_logs
```

... from the command line and point your browser to `htttp://localhost:6006`. See the example code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42112260/712995).

To check for vanishing / exploding gradients, pay attention the gradients distribution and absolute values in the layer of interest ("Distributions" tab):

- If the distribution is highly peaked and concentrated around 0, the gradients are probably vanishing. Here's a [concrete example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48816873/712995) how it looks like in practice.
- If the distribution is rapidly growing in absolute value with time, the gradients are exploding. Often the output values at the same layer become `NaN`s very quickly as well.

Comment: Also, for this to work you need to have `histogram_freq > 1` and therefore validation data (which cannot be a generator, even a sequence).

Comment: Setting write_grads=True does not show gradients for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: @J.J. write_grads=True is currently deprecated in the latest versions of tensorflow (2.1.0) https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31173 I'm looking for a solution at the moment as well.

Comment: @ElegantCode Did you find any solutions??

Comment: @ch271828n , The only answer I keep getting is to write your own callbacks to save the gradients and visualize them yourself.

Comment: @ElegantCode Could you please provide some sample code / repo? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the code here can be adapted for Feed forward networks as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017288/how-to-visualize-rnn-lstm-gradients-in-keras-tensorflow

Comment: @FrancescoBoi , Unfortunately not. You either write your own custom callback (https://keras.io/examples/vision/visualizing_what_convnets_learn/    OR   https://keras.io/examples/vision/integrated_gradients/ ) to record the gradients, or you could try to infer by using some indirect indications, for example seeing that the distribution of weights in TensorBoard changes a bit throughout the NN, or that the loss steadily decreases. But at the end of the day, these are approximations, with many issues.

Comment: You mean writing a new callback with `on_epoch_end` or subclassing the `keras.callbacks.TensorBoard()` callback or subclassing the optimizer (where the gradient is computed)? Sorry but the information about this is scattered and I can't come to grips.