# TensorFlow: How can I inspect gradients and weights in eager execution?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent, eager-execution

I am using TensorFlow 1.12 in eager execution, and I want to inspect the values of my gradients and my weights at different points during training for debugging purposes. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48928133/4028648) uses TensorBoard to get nice graphs of weight and gradient distribution over epochs, which is what I would like. However, when I use [Keras' TensorBoard callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard), I get this:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Weight and gradient histograms not supported for eagerexecution, setting `histogram_freq` to `0`.
```

In other words, this is not compatible with eager execution. Is there any other way to print gradients and/or weigths? Most non-TensorBoard answers seem to rely on graph-based execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In eager execution, you can directly print the weights. As for the gradients, you can use [tf.GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) to get the gradients of the loss function with respect to some weights. Here is an example showing how to print gradients and weights:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

x = tf.ones(shape=(4, 3))
y = tf.ones(shape=(4, 1))
dense = tf.layers.Dense(1)

# Print gradients
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    h = dense(x)
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, h)
gradients = t.gradient(loss, dense.kernel)
print('Gradients: ', gradients)

# Print weights
weights = dense.get_weights()
print('Weights: ', weights)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can this method be used in conjunction with `tf.fit()`, in order to print gradients over multiple epochs? Since that function abstracts away to loss taking and weights updating, I wouldn´t know how to get (the kernel of), say, my input layer and the loss "in the same place" and to feed those to the `t.gradient` function.

Comment: @EmielBoss do you mean [tf.keras.Model.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)? If that's the case you could either (1) not use `tf.keras.Model.fit` implement your custom training algorithm or (2) implement a [custom keras callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_callback) (wherein you print the weights/gradients, e.g. in the method `on_epoch_end`) and pass it to the argument `callbacks` of  `tf.keras.Model.fit`.